# BMW 530xd E60 2008 diesel possibly fuel pump problem

Tags: bmw, fuel-system, relay

Car details:

```
BMW 530xd
E60
2008-05
Diesel
170kw.
```

The pump is working as it should be, it has been tested in BMW center. Problem is, when I turn the ignition on, the check engine light doesn't come up for about 4 minutes 30 seconds and in that time I am unable to start the car. (it's only happening in cold whether, when it's about +2 to -5...n), when the engine is warm, this light comes up instantly when I turn the ignition on. I can hear a sound of something working while I am waiting for this light to come up, once it comes up, I can hear the sound more clearly. Once I've start the engine, this light goes off as expected. But the problem is this 4 mins delay after turning the ignition. I've read a lot about this problem and it all leads to the fuel pump relay.

Comment: What symptoms are leading you to the fuel pump relay? Can you hear the pump run for a few seconds after turning the ignition on? Several forums also recommend making sure you have at least 1/4 tank of fuel as E60 pumps show early signs of failure when fuel is low but not empty. I have tested fuel pumps by hitting the tank with a rubber hammer. If it starts it is generally the pump.

Comment: I've edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: The fuel pump relay is on the fascia fuse box, behind the glove box. It is the corner most relay of the two.

Comment: Thanks @Allan, I didn't realize that there is another fuse box, thought the only one is located in the trunk.

Answer (score 1):

you might need to check the relays in the fuse box, without forgetting the fuel regulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something blocking fuel lines, maybe hose bend. After some time under pressure of fuel pump it unblocks and fuel rail pressure returns to normal. Not sure that ECU has fuel pressure sensor, so it is just a theory but it worth to check fuel pressure first